# How can I get this code to output changing mass values given increments from the user?

Tags: visual-c++

The program outputs the mass, but only what the user inputs. The math that 
 should add the increment to the mass is not occurring. Could somebody help with 
 this?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
int main()
{
    float mass;
    float acceleration;
    float force;
    int calc1;
    int calc2;
    int calc3;
    float mass2;
    float increment;
    printf("Insert acelleration and mass below to calculate \nforce of a 
    given obect's movement.\n");
    printf("Mass (kg):\n");
    scanf("%f", &mass);
    printf("Acceleration (m/s/s):\n");
    scanf("%f", &acceleration);
    printf("Input Mass increment:\n");
    scanf("%i", &increment);
    calc2 = 1;
    mass2 = mass + increment;
    force = mass * acceleration;
    do
    {
        printf("%f(Kg)\t%f(M/s^2)\t%f(Newtons)\n", mass2, acceleration, 
        force);
        calc2++;
    } while (calc2 <= calc1);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updates to `mass2` and `force` should probably happen inside the loop. At the moment, these happen just once, before the loop.

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't work. Same result as before, no mass change.

Comment: You use `calc1` in the loop condition - but you never initialize it. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: You probably meant `mass = mass + increment;` , and then use `mass` everywhere you currently use `mass2`. As written, you aren't actually implementing anything, you just add the same values over and over.

Comment: I tried that, and the values are still not adding.

Comment: `scanf("%i", &increment);` This exhibits undefined behavior. `%i` format specifier expects an `int*` pointer as an argument, but `increment` is a `float`. With all the fixes, [the code works](http://rextester.com/DZDA28675)

Comment: Very good! Thank you all, now this thing actually works.